# Serialize Form to Array of Objects using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization

I am trying to serialize all inputs in a specific form into an object array so that I can pass it to my controller action and then update multiple rows at once.  My issue is the serializing part...  It's messing up somehow.

Here is where I generate the form:

```
$.each(content, function (i, item) {
                    var html = "<br />Choice ID<br /><input type='text' name='QuestionChoicesId' value='"
                        + item.QuestionChoicesId + "'><br />Choice Display Text<br /><input type='text' name='DisplayText'  value='"
                        + item.DisplayText + "'><br />Order of Display<br /><input type='text' name='OrderNumber' value='"
                        + item.OrderNumber
                        + "'>";
                    $(html).appendTo("#choices");
                });
```

This is what i am trying to do:

```
console.log($('#choices :input').serializeArray());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Question/UpdateQuestionchoices/",
            data: $('#choices :input').serialize()
        });
```

Here is the `console.log` output:

[image: output of serialize]

It should be an array of objects with `QuestionChoicesId`, `DisplayText`, and `OrderNumber` for each object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First would suggest you wrap each group, so a loop can be built over the wrappers

```
$.each(content, function (i, item) {
    var html = '<div class="control_group">';

    /* your exisiting string build code*/

    html += '</div>';
});
```

To create array:

```
var ajaxData = $('.control_group').map(function (idx,group) {
    var data = {};
    $(group).find(':input').each(function () {
        data[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    return data;
}).get();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wFjH3/2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use: **jquery.serializeToJSON** - https://github.com/raphaelm22/jquery.serializeToJSON
Its is prepared to work with forms ASP MVC

var obj = $("form").serializeToJSON();

Answer (score 0):

Although it may be structured like that, I think it posts as you would expect.  Did you look at how it was posted in the ajax call?  I have done the same thing and it worked as expected and bound correctly.

Comment: It wasn't mapping correctly in the controller.  Kept yelling about `NullReferenceException`.  So, I tracked the problem to the incorrect serialization of my form `<div>`.